# Latitude and Longitude get changed every time I fetch them at same position

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, android-fusedlocation

I am using android fused location api to get the latitude and longitude of same position but every time  i get different  latitude and longitude of same position last 4 digits vary every time at same position why so and how to get all the possible latitude & longitude of same position.

So please help me regarding this.

Comment: GPS has not that much accuracy for point. even you stay at one point for a long time it gives some variation.

Comment: Increase your get location `time interval`

Comment: @AnandMakwana yes, So what is the solution for it..?

Comment: @MD i am getting it in 15 minutes

Comment: You can calculate distance between old and new and make some distance prediction like >100m.

Comment: You can set the accuracy according to your needs and filter the location updates

Comment: @Gautam will you please elaborate?

Comment: you can use getAccuracy() method like if(location.getAccuracy <50) now you can either remove listening more updates as less than 50m accuracy fulfill your needs or do whatever you like.

Comment: Why was this question downgraded? The question is fully legitimate. This is right the decimals on the coords are changing at every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location is generally accurate to only a city block, and will change within that. Try rounding off the coordinates to two decimal places and use those.

Comment: Rounding two decimal places will not work, because even if you move to some 10 to 20 meters away from the desired location, the first two decimals of lati & long will be same.